# waiting for connection pool

Tags: linux, process, sockets

Using Ubuntu 14.04, `w3m` and `curl` (and, perhaps, my full-featured browsers) are taking a long time to connect.

I think it is due to something like waiting for a socket on the system, but am looking for advice on what tools I could use to check what’s going on. ([netstat](https://jvns.ca/zines/)?)

---

Here is some of what I have tried so far:

- `ping google.com` says it takes ~50 ms, but the terminal
- `time checkip.amazonaws.com` similarly takes ~50ms
- I have a lot of `tty`'s open (so many that I can't open new terminals)
- the time to `w3m` or `curl` things (from terminal) is very slow—over 1 minute
- I get errors like `Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :   cannot open URL: status was 'SSL connect error'`

---

So it seems like the problem is with local (¿socket?) connections rather than with the network itself.

How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: Is `curl` faster if you directly use the ip address of the server?

Comment: +1... very often it's a invalid address for one of your DNS and the delay you have is the DNS request timing out. Is ten services normally by the 2nd DNS in your list.